# wordpress I have class file which use for paypal express checkout Instead of express checkout i want to it replace to adaptive payment

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-nvp

/**
 * Class PayPal
 * @package Bookly\Lib\Payment
 */
class PayPal
{
    // Array for cleaning PayPal request
    static public $remove_parameters = array( 'action', 'token', 'PayerID', 'ab_fid', 'error_msg', 'type' );

```
/**
 * The array of products for checkout
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $products = array();

/**
 * Send the Express Checkout NVP request
 *
 * @param $form_id
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function send_EC_Request( $form_id )
{
    if ( !session_id() ) {
        @session_start();
    }

    if ( ! count( $this->products ) ) {
        throw new \Exception( 'Products not found!' );
    }

    $total = 0;

    // create the data to send on PayPal
    $data = array(
        'SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'Sole',
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'  => get_option( 'ab_currency' ),

        'NOSHIPPING' => 1,
        'RETURNURL'  => add_query_arg( array( 'action' => 'ab-paypal-return', 'ab_fid' => $form_id ), Lib\Utils\Common::getCurrentPageURL() ),
        'CANCELURL'  => add_query_arg( array( 'action' => 'ab-paypal-cancel', 'ab_fid' => $form_id ), Lib\Utils\Common::getCurrentPageURL() )
    );

    foreach ( $this->products as $index => $product ) {
        $data[ 'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME' . $index ] = $product->name;
        $data[ 'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' . $index ]  = $product->price;
        $data[ 'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY' . $index ]  = $product->qty;

        $total += ( $product->qty * $product->price );
    }
    $data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT']     = $total;
    $data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'] = $total;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    exit;
    // send the request to PayPal
    $response = self::sendNvpRequest( 'SetExpressCheckout', $data );

    // Respond according to message we receive from PayPal
    if ( 'SUCCESS' == strtoupper( $response['ACK'] ) || 'SUCCESSWITHWARNING' == strtoupper( $response['ACK'] ) ) {
        //$paypalurl = 'https://www' . get_option( 'ab_paypal_ec_mode' ) . '.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=' . urldecode( $response['TOKEN'] );
        $paypalurl = 'https://www' . get_option( 'ab_paypal_ec_mode' ) . '.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&useraction=commit&token=' . urldecode( $response['TOKEN'] );

        header( 'Location: ' . $paypalurl );
        exit;
    } else {
        header( 'Location: ' . wp_sanitize_redirect( add_query_arg( array( 'action' => 'ab-paypal-error', 'ab_fid' => $form_id, 'error_msg' => str_replace( ' ', '%20', $response['L_LONGMESSAGE0'] ) ), Lib\Utils\Common::getCurrentPageURL() ) ) );
        exit;
    }
}

/**
 * Send the NVP Request to the PayPal
 *
 * @param       $method
 * @param array $data
 * @return array
 */
public function sendNvpRequest( $method, array $data )
{
    $url  = 'https://api-3t' . get_option( 'ab_paypal_ec_mode' ) . '.paypal.com/nvp';
    $curl = new Lib\Curl\Curl();
    $curl->options['CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER'] = false;
    $curl->options['CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST'] = false;

    $data['METHOD']    = $method;
    $data['VERSION']   = '76.0';
    $data['USER']      = get_option( 'ab_paypal_api_username' );
    $data['PWD']       = get_option( 'ab_paypal_api_password' );
    $data['SIGNATURE'] = get_option( 'ab_paypal_api_signature' );

    $httpResponse = $curl->post( $url, $data );
    if ( ! $httpResponse ) {
        exit( $curl->error() );
    }

    // Extract the response details.
    parse_str( $httpResponse, $PayPalResponse );

    if ( ! array_key_exists( 'ACK', $PayPalResponse ) ) {
        exit( 'Invalid HTTP Response for POST request to ' . $url );
    }

    return $PayPalResponse;
}

public static function renderForm( $form_id )
{
    $html = '<form method="post" class="ab-paypal-form">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="ab-paypal-checkout"/>';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="ab_fid" value="' . $form_id . '"/>';
    $html .= '<button class="ab-left ab-back-step ab-btn ladda-button" data-style="zoom-in" data-spinner-size="40"><span class="ladda-label">' . Lib\Utils\Common::getTranslatedOption( 'ab_appearance_text_button_back' ) . '</span></button>';
    $html .= '<button class="ab-right ab-next-step ab-btn ladda-button" data-style="zoom-in" data-spinner-size="40"><span class="ladda-label">' . Lib\Utils\Common::getTranslatedOption( 'ab_appearance_text_button_next' ) . '</span></button>';
    $html .= '</form>';

    echo $html;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->products;
}

/**
 * Add the Product for payment
 *
 * @param \stdClass $product
 */
public function addProduct( \stdClass $product )
{
    $this->products[] = $product;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by adaptive payment? What exactly is the issue you ran into? And what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, i need paypal adaptive payment, i am trying to build plugin which shares % between owner and car driver..